# How to create new VM using the existing VHD in the Azure Blob storage?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have taken a backup of my azure VM VHD to blob storage using copy blob feature some time back.Now the VM is not present.Now i want to create the new VM using the Backup VHD in the another storage account using Power shell.

How can i do that using powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you can create a virtual machine you need to create a 'disk' over the blob copy. 
This can be done using the [Add-AzureDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152877.aspx)

Then you can create a Virtual Machine over an existing disk using `New-AzureVMConfig` and `New-AzureVM`, example of this has been published [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b8cbf55c-41c1-42f5-bc20-a45e6af55b61/powershell-syntax-for-adding-a-vm-with-an-existing-os-disk)  -

```
$vmI1 = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $machineName -InstanceSize Small -AvailabilitySetName 'RDGW' -DiskName 'MY-OS-Disk-Name' |
Add-AzureDataDisk -Import 'My-Data-Disk-0'  -LUN 0 |
Add-AzureDataDisk -Import 'My-Data-Disk-1' -LUN 1 |
Add-AzureEndpoint -Protocol tcp -LocalPort 443 -PublicPort 443 -Name 'HTTPs' |
Set-AzureSubnet $_subnetInternal, $_subnetDmz, $_subnetProtected
```

This creates the VM configuration which is then passed to New-AzureVM

Answer (score 3):

BTW: it's possible to create VM from VHD blob using web interface.
On Virtual Machines tab you can switch to sub tab Images and create new image using vhd from blob. 
Then it's possible to add new VM using existent vm image.

Comment: Please provide screen captures for how to do this. I can find no way in the Azure Portal to create a new image from a VHD.

Comment: It was perhaps only possible in the classic portal.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Azure Portal, after uploading your blob as a "page blob", click All Services and search for Image. Click `+Add` then define your image, select the blob, and you're off!